# How to enable & handle "tap" event on fabricjs on mobile device?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I want to handle event tap with fabricjs on mobile device. What is correct way to implement that ?

Currently, I see implement "tap" event in the fabricjs source code. And if I want handle that event, I need change fabricjs source code:

```
if (typeof eventjs !== 'undefined' && eventjsFunctor in eventjs) {
    eventjs[eventjsFunctor](canvasElement, 'gesture', this._onGesture);
    eventjs[eventjsFunctor](canvasElement, 'drag', this._onDrag);
    eventjs[eventjsFunctor](canvasElement, 'orientation', this._onOrientationChange);
    eventjs[eventjsFunctor](canvasElement, 'shake', this._onShake);
    eventjs[eventjsFunctor](canvasElement, 'longpress', this._onLongPress);
    eventjs[eventjsFunctor](canvasElement, 'tap', this._onLongPress);
  }
```

Add last line:

```
eventjs[eventjsFunctor](canvasElement, 'tap', this._onLongPress);
```

And now I can catch tap event through "longpress" event.

```
this.canvas.on({'touch:longpress': function(e) {
        console.log("touch:longpress + tap");
    });
```

My question is there another nice way to handle 'tap' event on fabricjs without modified fabricjs source code & can handle 'tap' event by listen "touch:tap" event name ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can add events to uppercanvas using

```
eventjs.add( canvas.upperCanvasEl, 'tap', onTap);
eventjs.remove( canvas.upperCanvasEl, 'tap', onTap);

function onTap(e) {
  console.log("tap");
})
```